# OpenLayers 3 Map Visualization

Tags: javascript, openlayers-3

Sorry if it is not the right place to ask this, but I couldn't find a answer anywhere and this have been bugging me.
I'm using openLayers 3.8.2 to create a map, and when I zoom out, the maps shows repeatedly... If I zoom out I can see many Americas, many Europes... etc
Does anyone know if there is a way to stop it from happening (besides defining a min zoom), because when I drag the map, sometimes, I can see the country I'm working one twice...

I saw that in a lot of OL examples, like [this one.](http://openlayers.org/en/master/examples/accessible.html)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can disable this using `wrapX: false`:

```
new ol.layer.Tile({
  source: new ol.source.OSM({
      wrapX: false
  })
})
```

See it in action: http://jsfiddle.net/war9k831/